# Counting inside Sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following problem. Given n_ for a square matrix.
n=3 Makes:

```
lst = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

Can this be done with Map[?
I can do it easily with Table. However, I feel Map[ would be an improvement. Is that right, also? (Part 2 of my question.)

```
amake[n_]:=Table[idx*n+jdx,{idx,0,n-1},{jdx,1,n}]
amake[4]
(* Out: {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}} *)
```

I can do it with one Map[ and one Table[. *However, I am trying to understand deeper list manipulation better. Reading Wellin and working problems.*

```
bmake3b[n_]:=Table[Map[(i-1)n+#&,Range[n]],{i,1,n}]
bmake3b[4]
(* Out: {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}} *)
```

Trying, almost works?

```
bmake2c[n_]:=Map[Map[(#-1)n+#&,Range[n]]&,Range[n]]
bmake2c[3]
(* Out: {{1,5,9},{1,5,9},{1,5,9}} *)
```

Comment: `Partition[Range[n^2], n]`?

Comment: OK, I hadn't read about Partition command yet, thank you. Although, can you do it with Map[? That was a question within the question?

Comment: try also `ArrayReshape[Range[n^2], {n, n}]`

Comment: You can do it without `Table` and with only one `Map` function.  `Map[(# - 1) n + Range[n] &, Range[n]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4]
f1[n_] := Map[n (# - 1) + Range[n] &, Range[n]]
f2[n_] := Partition[Range[n^2], n]
f3[n_] := ArrayReshape[Range[n^2], {n, n}]
f4[n_] := TakeList[Range[n^2], ConstantArray[n, n]]

f1[5] == f2[5] == f3[5] == f4[5]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
BlockMap[#&,Range[16],4]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}